# What is wrong with my coding? it doesn't collide

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Here is the code, it is 100% running. I'm trying to research the answer but I cannot find/solve it. The two sprites don't collide with each other. I want the collision function to run.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });
```

function preload() {

```
game.load.spritesheet('mummy', 'metalslug_mummy37x45.png', 37, 45, 18);
game.load.spritesheet('sprite', 'sprite.png', 39, 40);
game.load.image('background', 'cemetery.jpg');

}
var sprites;
var rip = 0;
var s;
```

function create() {

```
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');

    sprites = game.add.group();
    game.time.events.loop(80, createSprite, this);
    game.physics.enable(sprites, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    s = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'sprite');
    s.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    s.scale.setTo(2, 2);

    s.animations.add('run');
    s.animations.play('run', 10, true);
    game.physics.enable(s, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);



}
```

function createSprite() {

```
    var mummy = sprites.create(0, game.world.randomY, 'mummy');

    mummy.animations.add('walk');

    mummy.play('walk', 10, true);

}
```

function update() {

```
    sprites.setAll('x', 10, true, true, 1);

    sprites.forEach(checkSprite, this, true);

    game.physics.arcade.collide(s, sprites, collisionHandler, null, this);

    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
    {
        s.x -= 5;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
    {
        s.x += 5;
    }

    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP))
    {
        s.y -= 5;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN))
    {
        s.y += 5;
    }


}
```

function collisionHandler (obj1, obj2) {

```
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#992d2d';

}
```

function checkSprite(sprite) {

```
    try {
        if (sprite.x > game.width)
        {
            rip++;
            sprites.remove(sprite, true);
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(sprite);
    }

}
```

function render() {

```
    game.debug.text("Score: " + rip, 32, 64);

}
```

Comment: you have to explain your problem much better: what is expected, what is happening, any errors, ...

Comment: *"Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem -

```
`  sprites.setAll('x', 10, true, true, 1);

   sprites.forEach(checkSprite, this, true);`
```

you should write these inside **create** function not **update** function and make sure you call **game.physics.arcade.collide(//.....//);** at the beginning of your update function.

Comment: i try it but the group of mummy didn't move, it stay in the left side only . Also the collide function didn't still work.

Comment: it will be more easier to debug if you upload the code in jsbin/jsfiddle with some assets.